# Ambiguous reference to member 'from(jsonArray:)'

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am trying to build a project on xcode and i am getting this error.
I am using gloss pod 
Any Help with this

[image]

Comment: Please avoid images when you need to add code. Try to change it as text.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask You should put your code instead of screenshots

Comment: All of the model must be the type of Glossy. Please check

Comment: @shivi_shub i noticed that they weren't of type Glossy.Thank

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you declared the array of type something, and initializing with some other type.

The response what you are getting from jsonArray is not matching with the array's type what you have created.
Check **MerchantUserModel**, **PromotionModel**, **CategoryModel**, **MerchantModel** declaration.

Then Compare with the jsonResponse,  wheather both the structures matching or not.

Eg. jsonResponse might be ArrayOfDictionary, ArrayOfArrays, Dictionaries etc.